# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'partitionBy'

Tags: pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

i write a code for partitioning the data on Year and Month but i am getting an error

```py
data.write.csv('/tmp/fold',header=True) \   
  .partitionBy('YEAR','MONTH').mode('overwrite')
```

This is how my data look like

```
EmpId|  EName|       DOJ|YEAR|MONTH|
+-----+-------+----------+----+-----+
|    1|Anubhav|2020-02-02|2020|   02|
|    2|    Raj|2021-01-22|2021|   01|
|    3|   jaya|2020-11-29|2020|   11|
|    4|hiamani|2022-09-12|2022|   09|
```

Do you know the reason

Answer (score 1):

the `.partitionBy('YEAR','MONTH').mode('overwrite')` should be before `.csv(...)`, not after:

```py
data.write \
  .partitionBy('YEAR','MONTH').mode('overwrite') \
  .csv('/tmp/fold',header=True)
```

the `.save`, `.csv`, `.parquet`, `.saveAsTable`, ... - they should be the last operations in the chain of the command because they don't return any result (so you get `None`)

Comment: In Pyspark order is also important?

Comment: When chaining operations - yes.